# What are Compound Key and SuperKey?

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

I have already been through their respective Wikipedia page [Compound Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) and [Super Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey). I really couldn't understand the concept. I am looking for very plain and simple explanation as given in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736261/what-are-candidate-key-alternate-key-composite-key-in-sql#answer-10736313)(not necessarily one liners but with examples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A superkey is any combination of attributes that are required to be unique for all possible values of a relation.

A candidate key is a minimal superkey. Minimal means that if any attribute of the superkey was removed then the remaining set of attributes would no longer be a superkey, i.e. the uniqueness property would be lost. Put another way, every superkey consists of a candidate key plus zero or more other attributes.

A compound key - also called a composite key - is a candidate key which has more than one attribute.

Answer (score 1):

A super key (called primary or unique in sql server) uniquely identifies a row in the table. ie it only returns one row. 
A compound key does the same thing, but is composed of more than one field.

So if you were a bit new and keyed your table of employees by Surname and FirstName, that would be the super key, and it would be a compound key, because its more than one field.

Comment: _Super key_ may composed of one or more columns but _Compound key_ will composed of 2 or more columns. And if _Super Key_ is composed of only 1 column it cannot be _Compound Key_. Is that correct?

Comment: Aye. More isn't than can't be though.

Comment: @barnes Note that a superkey doesn't have to be a minimal key (aka candidate key).

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the essential difference: a superkey is unique; a compound key is *irreducibly* unique (i.e. a minimal superkey).

Comment: @sqlvogel I'd really appreciate if you could provide your side of the story(an answer) in very simple english. :)

Comment: @reaanb Could you please provide an elaborated explanation to your comment.

Comment: A candidate key is a minimal set of columns required to uniquely identify each row. There may be multiple candidate keys in a relation. A superkey is any superset of columns that includes at least one candidate key. See this answer: [What are the differences between a superkey and a candidate key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519825/what-are-the-differences-between-a-superkey-and-a-candidate-key)

Answer (score 1):

A compound key is a key having 2 or more attributes while A superkey is a combination of columns that uniquely identifies any row within an RDBMS table.

Comment: Careful there, a key of any type, uniquely identifies a row (tuple). "Its the key to finding one row". Think an index, that could also be a single or compound but may identify more than one row. If it does, it is not a key.